# Is calling an EJB inside another EJB healthy?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am creating a document sharing platform under Java EE, JSF/Primefaces and hibernate. For each data object (document, repositories and users) I created a `List<Event> events;` to store various events (users creation, document modifications, etc.).

To respect the layered architecture, I have a Model layer where I define data objects, a Business layer where I define my Session beans (which contain the logic) and the presentation layer where are defined the views of my application.

I created a Session bean for each data object to code its handling. So I have a `EventsSessionBean` to handle the persistence and fetching of events as long as `UserSessionBean`, `DocumentSessionBean` etc.

When creating a User, for example, I need to persist the `UserCreated` event in the data base before. Hence, I have to call the method `public Event createEvent(String label);` in the `UserSessionBean` from the `EventsSessionBean`.

Is this a "healthy" coding way? I am afraid I am getting responsibilities mixed between my beans.

Code snippet :

```
//Class definition
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@EJB
private EventSessionBeanLocal eventService;
public static final String EVENT_USER_CREATION = "UserCreated";

public  RepositoryOwner createRepositoryOwner(/* username, email, ..etc*/){
    Event event = eventService.createEvent(EVENT_USER_CREATION);
    RepositoryOwner newUser = new RepositoryOwner();
    LinkedList<Event> events = new new LinkedList<>();
    events.add(event);
    newUser.setEvents(events);
    //Set other user attributes
    newUser = em.merge(newUser);
    return newUser;
}
```

Is it wrong to think that `UserSessionBean` when dealing with events is acting on something that is out of its scope?

Comment: It is totally healthy.

Comment: With only a redacted description of the code its impossible to say if what is actually done is healthy or not. It is of course perfectly fine to invoke EJBs from within EJBs (in fact - you should), but that doesn't mean that whatever code you have is doing the right thing.

Comment: @Gimby what do you think?

Comment: @Hichamov Flat simple code which is readable and properly separates concerns in such a way that code is reusable. Beats me why you doubt what's right in front of you.

Comment: I am the most concerned of the responsibility of each of my beans. I would easily think, in the case of the question, that the `UserSessionBean` is dealing with events creation which is out of its scope

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with this, it is common practice. One other approach (weather it can be applied or not depends on you requirements and business logic) would be to have a message queue (MQ) which you would utilize for such tasks. For example, your `UserSessionBean` would add a message to the queue when user is created, and some [message driven bean (MDB)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html) would get that message, and call `EventSessionBean` to persist the event.

But, as I said, it depends on your requirement if this can be used well or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My requirements are pretty loose, I'll be looking at the MDB approach (never worker with one)